# How can I train a neural network to find the hyper-parameters with which the data was generated?

Tags: gradient-descent, pytorch

I have 10000 tuples of numbers `(x1, x2, y)` generated from the equation: `y = np.cos(0.583 * x1) + np.exp(0.112 * x2)`. I want to use a neural network, trained with gradient descent, in PyTorch, to find the 2 parameters, i.e. 0.583 and 0.112

Here is my code:

```
class NN_test(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.7))
        self.b = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.02))

    def forward(self, x):
        y = torch.cos(self.a*x[:,0])+torch.exp(self.b*x[:,1])
        return y

model = NN_test().cuda()

lrs = 1e-4
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = lrs)
loss = nn.MSELoss()

epochs = 30
for epoch in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    for i, dtt in enumerate(my_dataloader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        inp = dtt[0].float().cuda()
        output = dtt[1].float().cuda()

        ls = loss(model(inp),output)

        ls.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    if epoch%1==0:
        print("Epoch: " + str(epoch), "Loss Training: " + str(ls.data.cpu().numpy()))
```

where `x` contains the 2 numbers `x1` and `x2`. In theory, it should work easily, but the loss doesn't go down. What am I doing wrong?